# Weakly inaccessible cardinals and Discovering Modern Set Theory

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

So I've been trying to teach myself some set theory and I've come across some exercises in Just and Weese's Discovering Modern Set Theory. To whit:

Pg. 180

Definition 20: A cardinal $\kappa$ is called weakly inaccessible if $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular limit cardinal.

Exercise 27 (PG): Show that if $\alpha$ is a weakly inaccessible cardinal, then $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$.

Exercise 28 (R): Show that the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$ is not a weakly inaccessible cardinal.

Ends

For the first I've proved by induction that $\alpha\subseteq\aleph_\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$, obviously I have to use the weakly inaccessible part to go the other way, but I've no idea where to start. Weakly inaccessible gives that every function with cofinal range in $\alpha$ has domain at least $\alpha$ but that is saying that things are big, where as I need that $\aleph_\alpha$ is small.

The second is beyond me, I considered trying to show that ZFC proves the existence of such an ordinal $\alpha$, and then appeal to the fact that the existence of a weakly inaccessible cardinal is independent of ZFC, however this result is yet to be obtained in the text and so I imagine this can't be what is wanted.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is easier, simply define by recursion $\lambda_0=\mu$, $\lambda_{n+1}=\aleph_{\lambda_n}$, for $n\in\omega$ ($\mu$ is any cardinal). Then calculate what is $\lambda_\omega=\sup\{\lambda_n\mid n\in\omega\}$.

The first one is not much harder either. Because $\aleph_\alpha$ is limit, $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. Pick a cofinal sequence in $\alpha$, $\langle\delta_i\mid i<\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)\rangle$. Consider the sequence $\aleph_{\delta_i}$. What is its limit? What can you conclude on $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)$ from the assumption that $\aleph_\alpha$ is regular as well?

Comment: Thanks, I guess you are dubious of the difficulty rating system if you think the second is easier.

Comment: I am; but also the second one is just a trick. And once you get that trick it's very easy to solve; but the first one relies on no tricks. It's just verifying the definitions and that can be a pain in the backside area which connects the thighs with the lower back.

Comment: Clearly $\lambda_\omega$ has $\lambda_\omega = \aleph_{\lambda_\omega}$, but I think the 'R' rating there comes from the fact that it's not immediately obvious that it's the _smallest_ cardinal of that form, or even that there isn't an inaccessible smaller than it.  (It's pretty straightforward, but still takes a bit more arguing, I think.)

Comment: I kinda like the trick, it feels like approximating what you want and taking the limit, which I suppose is precisely what you are doing.

Comment: @James: It's not quite *that* trick, this is the trick we use in many other areas (e.g. forcing). I can't quite describe this trick in nice words, though. Maybe it's just getting late...

Comment: Or maybe the fact that we say $a$ extends $b$ if $a<b$ has made you crack. This is basically all I know about forcing...

Comment: @James: I see that you're supporting the Jerusalem convention, even before understanding the very idea of forcing. Well, if one uses Boolean algebras to do their forcing, then extending downwards is a very reasonable idea.

Comment: Well I prefer to make my value judgments in a state of ignorance. Although I think I understand the idea of forcing, you have some partial order and you use this to add generics and magically that breaks CH or whatever. See, total understanding.

Answer (score 5):

For Exercise $28$ let $\alpha_0=0$. Given $\alpha_n$, let $\alpha_{n+1}=\aleph_{\alpha_n}$. Then

$$\alpha=\sup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n=\sup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_{n+1}=\sup_{n\in\omega}\aleph_{\alpha_n}=\aleph_\alpha\;,$$

but $\operatorname{cf}\alpha=\omega<\alpha$. It’s not hard to see that this $\alpha$ is the smallest ordinal satisfying $\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$.

**Added:** For Exercise $27$ you’ve already shown that $\alpha\le\aleph_\alpha$. If $\alpha<\aleph_\alpha$, then $\alpha=\aleph_\beta$ for some $\beta<\alpha$, so $\operatorname{cf}\alpha\le\beta<\alpha$, contradicting the regularity of $\alpha$.